# <Alt> + Middle Mouse Button

Tags: 18.10

In Ubuntu 18.10's gnome dconf editor, is there a way to bind:

raise-or-lower

to

['Alt MMB’]

where MMB is middle mouse button? I’ve been so used to that in Unity that I wish gnome would allow me to do that.

Thanks.